# C++14 : No match for 'operato r='

Tags: c++, pytorch, c++14

I am facing this problem ( no match for operator =) with this line and I cannot figure it out.

```cpp
std ::shared_ptr<torch::jit::script::Module> module;

try {
module = torch::jit::load(argv[1]); //error here
}
```

please help

Comment: We're going to need more code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], and also a *full* and *complete* copy-paste (as text) of the build output.

Answer (score 0):

Generalized to an int you get the same error:

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<int> module;

  module = 10;
}
```

No operator= because shared_ptr does not have it for that type. You need to use std::make_shared to create an Module shared pointer.

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<int> module;

  module = std::make_shared<int>(10);

}
```